# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1779).

Comment: Does this mean that community ads made to the previous size are no longer acceptable?  I think this is a serious problem.  Community ads are done in people's free time.  A lot of work went into some of the ads and [they were designed to look good in the old size](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5890/6302).  People won't be able to make something completely new *right now* just because it's the new year.  There should be at least a few months before the old size becomes unacceptable.

Comment: The ad (only one so far) is appearing stretched widthwise in the sidebar. This is explicitly contrary to what we were promised [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment884976_272563). Is StackExchange interested in fixing this?

Comment: It seems to be working as promised now. If you fixed anything, or asked for it to be fixed--thanks.

Comment: The ad below is not being shown on the main site and old ads from 2015 are still being served. Any ideas if/when the switch will happen?

Comment: @R.M. The switch should've been thrown last month. I'll check on it today.

Comment: @GraceNote Is there an A/B test with the old and new? I only see ads from 2015, but the stats for 2016 show a few clicks on the ad below, so _somebody_ is seeing it...

Comment: @GraceNote The placeholder that is shown when creating a new post here still has the old, narrow size, not the new 300 by 250 one.

Comment: @Szabolcs Huh, thanks for the update. Coulda swore we got that fixed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Answer (score 22):

[image: Mathematica syntax highlighter for LaTeX]

Answer (score 20):

[image: PackageData.net: Mathematica Package Repository]

Comment: [Sometimes it doesn't quite fit.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjabxrabuemsxkm/Screenshot%202016-07-05%2021.30.07.png?dl=0)  I like the dynamically changing display, but I really liked the design of the previous ad.

Comment: @Szabolcs I fixed that problem now. I might switch back to the older ad in a while, right now I just want to show that using Wolfram Cloud is viable (at least for this type of simple ad.)

Comment: Here's the font selection we can use: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120102/12

Comment: @Szabolcs How do you interpret [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkfjv.png)? It's Courier again, on my computer it looks like I expected, in Wolfram Cloud it looks like what Karsten posted. But it's still Courier right? It has the same shape?

Comment: I think (guess) that Courier, Helvetica and Times are special names that may map to similar but different fonts on different platform.  If you choose Courier New for the local rendering, it'll be closer to what the cloud gives (about the same weight), but still distinct from it.

Comment: [Article with countless variants of Courier](http://www.rolandstroud.com/downloads/essays/courierfonts.pdf)  I still think that we are looking at different fonts and not different renderings by different type engines of the very same font.

Comment: How are your cloud credits doing with this?

Comment: @rcollyer It's seemingly unaffected, at most I've been down to 1247 credits but for a while now I've been at 1250 which is as much as I ever have.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Mathematica palette to upload content to StackExchange easily]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Combine the power of igraph and Mathematica]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Check out the generative-art tag!]

Comment: The code to generate this image is here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1905/12

Answer (score 15):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 12):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/mathematica.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Answer (score 12):

[image: A Mathematica package for sharing images and code with StackExchange]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Join the Mathematica chat on StackExchange]

Comment: Man, that's such an unscratchable itch. Add a space, maybe? Please? Pretty please? :-)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A space where?

Comment: Between Our and Chat. Camel case is awesome, but this is inside a string, right?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Try reading it by deferring the evaluation... It reads **Join our chat** (allowing for reasonable artistic freedom)  ;)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I asked in chat if someone can make sense of your comment because I did not understand it. To me, it was clear that it reads "Join our chat" and I was puzzled what you could possibly mean :)

Comment: It was meant as a joke. The message is obvious (and the pun is well done), but evaluating that expression returns `"OurChat"`, without a space, and that looks weird inside a string to me. That's all.

Comment: Hehe.. I really wasn't sure how obvious it was. That's why I asked. No harm done :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mathematica Programming: An Advanced Introduction]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Download David Wagners book for free]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?]

Comment: This ad is made with Mathematica.  Code is available on request (because I'm lazy to clean it up).  Graphics: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13256/12

Answer (score 10):

[image: What are the most common pitfalls availing new users?]

Comment: This ad is made with Mathematica.  Code is available on request (because I'm lazy to clean it up).  Graphics: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13256/12

Comment: It makes kind of an apocaliptic impression, don't know why but I like it ;)

Answer (score 10):

[image: An elementary introduction to the Wolfram Language]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Seamlessly call MATLAB from Mathematica]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Wolfram Programming Lab]